# Junit for MessageBoxProvider

Tags: java, junit, rcp

I have code like below

```
      if (MessageBoxProvider.questionMessageBox(shell, title, message)) {
            return performOverwrite(file);
        }
```

I wanted to test(JUnit) how many times performOverwrite(file) method called, I know I can use verify method to test, my problem is `MessageBoxProvider.questionMessageBox(shell, title, message)` , condition will become only true when user clicks ok, but Using Junits, how can I make `if` condition true?

Comment: use powermock like framework to mock out your static call and let it expect the call and you say that method to return true.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing business logic becomes very complicated if user-interface code is mixed in with it. Ideally, you should adopt a design pattern, such as MVC or MVP that prevents this entirely.

If you can't or won't go down that route, consider defining an interface that contains all your message box methods. E.g.

```
public interface MessagePrompter {
  boolean poseQuestion(title, message);

  // ...
}
```

In your class constructor, accept an object of this type and store it. In your tests, you can mock this object and use it to control what the test user has done.

In your production code, use a concrete implementation of this interface that calls your `MessageBoxProvider` methods.

This type of approach has the benefit of making your application more portable. If you want to release a command-line version or a web-based version, you simply change the way your concrete implementation behaves.

Comment: Is there any way to test it maintaining existing code?

Comment: @Ganesh The approach mentioned [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604220/junit-for-messageboxprovider/26604507#comment41821396_26604220) would be applicable.